# How do I use input_shape and input_tensor in Transfer Learning in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

When we do transfer learning in Keras2., the Arguments require "input_shape" and "input_tensor". But I use only input_tensor and haven never used input_shape. I think only input_tensor is enough, and I don't know when to use input_shape.
How should I use them separately?

I used input_tensor and input_shape simultaneously with separate value, and  only value of input_tensor was adopted and input_shape was ignored.

```py
vgg16_model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', 
                    input_tensor = Input(shape=(150, 150, 3)), 
                    input_shape=(224,224,3))

top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=vgg16_model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model = Model(input=vgg16_model.input, output=top_model(vgg16_model.output))

model.summary()
```

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
================================================================
input_6 (InputLayer)         (None, 150, 150, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 150, 150, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 150, 150, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 75, 75, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv......
```

I expected I get some errors in this code, but there was no error, and this model could accept the shape of (150, 150, 3). Input_shape=(224,224,3) was ignored.

Can you maybe give me a little help ? Thanks.

Comment: Both are optional arguments when the fully connected classification layers aren't used. These models can accept variable sized inputs, but will then deliver variable sized outputs

Comment: Thanks! but I still have a question. I added details of code.
When must I use input_shape instead of input_tensor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `VGG16` code probably simply forgot to check for the two arguments.

It doesn't make sense to have both, of course.

- You use `input_shape` when you want the model to create its own input layer automatically with that size.
- You use `input_tensor` when you have a tensor that you want to be the input.

You can use **any** tensor in `input_tensor`, this is meant to use the outputs of other models/layers as the input of the `VGG16`. Of course that you can pass a dummy input tensor as you did, there is no reason for the code to complain, it received a tensor, ok.

The only thing there is that the coder forgot to verify "if both arguments exist, thrown an error".

Comment: Thank you so much!, and I found the way to connect other models/layers.
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/8999

Keras has some bugs about it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, when you set the `input_tensor` argument, the given tensor (assuming it is a Keras tensor) will be used for the input and therefore the `input_shape` argument would be ignored. [Here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/065c1ee7dbb9043c9fed571b086711d802d6bf31/keras_applications/vgg16.py#L101) is the relevant section in `keras-applications` source code:

```
if input_tensor is None:
    img_input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
else:
    if not backend.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
        img_input = layers.Input(tensor=input_tensor, shape=input_shape)
    else:
        img_input = input_tensor
```

As you can see, in the last line the given `input_tensor` will be used for the input tensor without considering the `input_shape`.

Comment: For the fits if statement of the else, I'm not sure what the logic means. If the input_tensor isn't a keras_tensor, then we want the placeholder of the tensor to be equal to the input tensor? Why is this the case? Thanks.

Comment: @IntegrateThis If it's a Keras tensor, then it means it is connected to a layer/model and from there it can take values; therefore, using it as it is would be fine. However, if it's not a Keras tensor it should be wrapped in a `Input` layer so that it could be fed (i.e. take values) using a `placeholder` (which is the underlying structure of `Input` layer).